# Can we get a minhag shtus tag?

Tags: feature-request, specific-tag, tags

There are lots of minhagim of dubious origins or worse and many, many teshuvot which refer to practices as minhag shtus. I submit [my most recent question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35621/who-escorts-the-queen-of-england-at-a-jewish-wedding) as evidence that questions about minhagei shtus do come up and would benefit from a tag.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone with [300 rep](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) on the main site can create new tags by just using them in a question. If a tag seems like something that applies to a bunch of questions and can be useful as a way of grouping them (and is not [a meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)), then go ahead and add it to some of those questions!

Comment: remembered that after posting. I already created the tag